Setting Up Shared User Directories on Ubuntu and QTS
Could you please help me with this setup:
Two machines:
Machine 1  = "workstation" (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS):
On this machine I have multiple users. Every on of this users should have a directory in his /home folder that is called e.g. "fileserver_username". It should act like a normal directory. The user should be able to read/write this directory and all other users should be able to read.
Machine 2 ="fileserver" (QTS 5.1.7.2770):
This is where the files are stored.
I have admin access to both machines.
I tried to setup NFS but it didn't work (but the issue is most certainly on my side, since I'm not very familiar with server setups). Now I read up and think SSHFS is a viable option.
It would be very much appreciated if you could point me in the right direction or if you could tell me another protocol which is more suitable for this scenario.
Is there an option, if I use SSHFS that not every user opens up his/her own SSH connection? Because from time to time big filrd (10GB+) will be moved so I think that I could encounter an issue with bandwith. So I would like to do it all over the same connection if possible .
Thanks in advance!

What didn't work with NFS? Why do you think sshfs is a better choice?

I just didn't get it to run and sadly didn't find a good tutorial

What did you try? You have a very open-ended question, which is probably a bad fit for this site.

The problem that i encountered was that I couldn't access the remote directory but was able to mount it. I think there could be an issue with the userid but couldn't really find a solution online.
My question is, if NFS is the right protocol for this situation or if something else would be a better fit.
I'm just started using Linux 2 month ago and I'm still nit very good at it.
I hope this clears up some issues
